# no such table: (code: 0) error Amplify.DataStore.save after schema change

Tags: amazon-web-services, datastore, aws-amplify

I am new to Amplify integration in iOS application. I am using Amplify DataStore for offline. Before it was working fine to save and retrieve user data from Amplify DataStore, then i change the Schema name just from Users to User. Now am facing this error when saving user data to DataStore:

```
"no such table: User(code: 0)"
```

After Schema change I run:

```
Amplify Push
```

Then
I clean the build.
Delete the application.
Delete the Amplify Folder

Run the amplify pull command:

```
Amplify pull and Amplify codegen models.
```

But still facing the issue. Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of debugging and search i finally found a solution.

```
 There was a duplicate key in one of my Schema modals. I just remove and deploy and pull, it start working.
```